# How to override default bash key-bindings?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline, inputrc

I write this config file:

```
# ~/.inputrc
Control-d: "\C-udate +'%F %T'\C-m"
```

I want to run `date` command when I type <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd>.
But I cannot override the default behavior(`exit`).
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `stty -a`, you'll notice that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> is bound to `eof` (end of file) for the terminal driver. You would have to unbind it using `stty` before the Bash binding would have any affect. I wouldn't recommend that you do that. It would be better to choose another keystroke. I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> for a similar purpose.

```
"\eD":"date +%A,\ %B\ %-d,\ %Y,\ %-l:%M:%S\ %p,\ %Z\ \(UTC%z\)"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the line discipline trumps readline. Try executing

```
stty eof undef
```